# 220µF 35V capacitor replacement

Tags: capacitor, automotive

I'm using this circuit to run a small device within my car (12V):

[image: circuit]

Now I need to consider the height of the PCB and C1 is currently 10mm height. Is there a way to replace this component either with an equivalent or with may be two/more capacitors?

Right now I use this guy: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/EEE-1VA221UP/PCE3955DKR-ND/1838721

Thanks in advance
JB

Comment: Just put two smaller ones in parallel?

Comment: Lay it on its side?

Comment: So replace the 220µF with one 100µV and one 150µV rated for the same voltage (35V)?

This is an SMD part, so laying on its side is to possible IMHO.

Comment: Use an axial mount (through-hole) part.

Comment: TBH, you could probably get away with a single smaller device regardless; that circuit isn't exactly rocket surgery.

Comment: I consider every input. What would you change @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: Just go with a shorter 150uF part.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So I will end up with 7.7mm with a single 150µF. Or take 1x 68µF + 1x 100µF with a height of 5.8mm each. Sounds a bit better.

Comment: If the two smaller parts are the same height then put two of the larger one of those; it will reduce BOM size.

Comment: Or use 3, 4 or more in parallel.

Comment: Just to keep things simple, if you use multiple capacitors, use two or more of the same value. For example, you could change 220uF to 2 x 100uF (it is close enough) or 4 x 56uF or 5 x 47 uF. If the circuit is known to work well, I would just try to keep a total of close to 200 uF, even though it seems like way more capacitance than should be needed. I've read that cars can put out some nasty voltage spikes. The capacitance might help with that.

Comment: The 220 microfarad 25V looks really nominal .You wont be punished for say a 16V or say a 150microfarad . this is not a spacecraft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, obtain the available volume (PCB area x height). Get a capacitor that fits into the volume and meets the voltage and capacitance requirements (=> 35v, => 220uf).